# How to add an app bar to a StatelessWidget?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

When I try to add this app bar It gives me an error. The error is : Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.

```
appBar: new AppBar(
  title: new Text("Appbar"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      child: Icon(Icons.search),
    ),
  ],
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
),
```

How do I add the Above appbar to the below code?

```
class StatisticsPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Welcome to Flutter",
      home: Statistics(),
    );
  }
}
class Statistics extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child:new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Colors.white,     
 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `appBar` property lies in the `Scaffold()` widget. You are trying to call the `appBar` in the build which will not work.

```
class Statistics extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Appbar"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

You seem new to Flutter or you are just copy-pasting code from some old repository.

The `new` keyword does not need to be applied anymore since Dart 2.0.
Learn Dart and then Flutter, you can start from Youtube tutorials.

Comment: It worked! yes, I'm quite new, gotta start somewhere right